# GCP command to get the CloudComposer airflow config value of core-dags_are_paused_at_creation variable

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

Someone please help me with the GCloud command to get the value of **core-dags_are_paused_at_creation** airflow config variable which is there in cloud composer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating the composer if we override the variable value then we get the value from composer override variables. Then we can use below command to get the value of overridden variable.

`gcloud composer environments describe "$ENVIRONMENT" --location "$LOCATION" --format="value(config.softwareConfig.airflowConfigOverrides.core-dags_are_paused_at_creation)"`